# How can I send email from frontend website without having to expose API Key?

Tags: email, web, server

I got a server from OVH and downloaded a template from html5up.
I then uploaded the template to the server : [root schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3xCI.png)

The thing is, I now want to send emails with a form that is on one of the html page.

The template has no backend, so I don't have any code where I can store API keys, or hide method that would call API to send email for me.
I found a solution that made me write an ajax call from the JS directly to the API Rest, but the API Key would be visible.

How could I proceed ? Am I forced to write a backend ? Can I just add a java file, or a php file that would call an API ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Yes, you'll need a backend to keep the key secret.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an open API, which does not require API keys.

Cuz, as soon as you use one with API keys, you have to find a way to hide/secure them, and the only approach is to setup your backend.

Massiles.